# Operator norm of $TT^*$

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $T:H \to H$ be a bounded operator

Prove that:$||TT^* ||=||T^*T || =||T||^2$
Any indication please

Comment: There's a classical proof on [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Norm_of_Adjoint)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $h∈H$ such that $‖h‖_H≤1$

Then:

$‖Ah‖^2_H =    ⟨Ah,Ah⟩_H
=    ⟨A^∗Ah,h⟩_H   
≤    ‖‖A^∗Ah‖‖_H‖h‖_H    
≤    ‖‖A^∗A‖‖‖h‖^2_H     
≤    ‖‖A^∗A‖‖   
≤    ‖‖A^∗‖‖‖A‖ $
Therefore:

$‖Ah‖‖‖Ah′‖‖ ≤    ‖‖A^∗‖‖‖A‖$
it follows that: $ ‖A‖2≤‖A^∗A‖≤‖A^∗‖‖A‖$

That is, $‖A‖≤‖A^∗‖$

By substituting $A^∗$ for $A$, and using $A^{∗∗}=A$ from Double Adjoint is Itself, the reverse inequality is obtained.

Hence $ ‖A‖^2=‖A^∗A‖=‖A^∗‖^2$